# Simple select query missing rows in Ignite

Tags: ignite

Selecting by ID over a table with 2 entries results in a single output result.

Here's the example table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person(
      id int,
      city_id int,
      name varchar,
      age int,
      company varchar,
      PRIMARY KEY (id, city_id)
    );
    INSERT INTO Person (id, name, city_id) VALUES (1, 'John Doe', 3);
    INSERT INTO Person (id, name, city_id) VALUES (1, 'John Dean', 4);
```

The following queries were executed in the same order:

```
"SELECT * FROM Person" returns both rows - expected
"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age is null" returns both rows - expected
"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id = 1" returns only the first row, when it was expected to return both rows.
```

Would you be able to help me understand what is going on here?
Thanks!

---

Edit

This is an active critical issue being tracked here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12068

Comment: I get two rows as a result. What version do you use?

Comment: I verified the queries that you provided on Ignite versions 2.7.0 and 2.7.5. In both cases I get 2 rows. Am I missing something?

Comment: What i see is that You have set up PRIMARY KEY (id, city_id) on ID, and u want to have same ID's for 2 records ? its not possible this must be unique. Meaby thats why u dont see 2 rows, beacouse second was changed by ignite

Comment: Thank you for verifying, Denis. I'm using latest, 2.7.5. Would be aware of any transient situation where a single row would return? Perhaps a cache problem? I'm just really puzzled that something like this is happening

Comment: @KubaDo, from what I understand, the primary key is setup to be a combination of both id and city_id, so the entries correspond to two different primary keys: (1,3) and (1,4). So as Denis reports, it should return 2 rows

Comment: Ok now I understood what You wanted to achieve, so You are missing syntax :

"CONSTRAINT": rework Your coder to this : CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (id, city_id)

this allows to combine 2 columns as PK

Comment: @ElderYoshida do you have this issue every time you run the queries? If I try running them, I get two rows as expected. Could you change the queries so that they return only one row as a result?

Comment: Hi folks, this is a bug in Apache Ignite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by the community and will be available in the upcoming release shortly:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12068

Thanks for reporting.